# What is the English term whose meaning covers both that of *Word* and *Title*?

Tags: vocabulary

I am developing an App for which I have need to find a word or term whose meaning would encompass both the words *Word* and *Title*.

Examples of a *Word*,  are "car", "mobile phone".
Examples of a *Title* would be "Car price went up this year" or "Mobile phone sales declined in US"

I need to to give a field name for such *words or titles*, and currently I am using the term "WordOrTitleID". This term is a bit clumsy, so I am looking for a term that would better cover both meanings.

If I used `TextID`, that would not be helpful because *text* can be anything?

If I used `ExpressionID`, that would also not be helpful because *expression* is quite ambiguous, plus users wouldn't be able to relate to it.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info on what the "Title" is title for? Because otherwise, I feel like just using "TitleID" should be appropriate enough? "Car" and "Mobile Phone" are words, but I see no reason why they can't also be referred to as titles, specially if they're serving the same position in your DB.

Comment: Title is like article title but not a sentence

Comment: I also think Title ID is enough, but the word can be used in a dictionary context so we can't say searching for title "car". The problem is I uses the same table for 2 different contexts (dictionary & article) so now i got tucked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming elements within program code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even for two different contexts like dictionary and articles, I think "TitleID" is still relevant, since both are titles of your entries in question.

Title can mean a descriptive heading or caption, as of a chapter, section, or other part of a book. The "word" that heads a dictionary entry can also be called its title.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your *Word* is a *Title* (while your title may not be a word). This would make the appropriate name `TitleID`.

Since you cannot use this name, and it sounds like this is the subject of more data, consider using `SubjectID`.